# Error: No provider for TemplateRef! Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-template

I am trying to learn how we can use template ref in my angular4 application, so far from the documentation i seem to understand, we can use the view from the  in the templateRef but when i tried to implement the same i get the following error

> ERROR Error: No provider for TemplateRef!

following is my code sample

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>, private element: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.template.createEmbeddedView(this.element);
  }
}

<ng-template>
    <div style='border: solid 2px yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #adadad;'>

    </div>
</ng-template>
<div style='border: solid 2px red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #adadad;'>

</div>
```

here what i want to implement is place the html present inside the component inside the .

**UPDATE 1**

i have changed my code to this

```
@ViewChild('tmp1') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
       this.template.createEmbeddedView(this.element.nativeElement);
  }


<ng-template #tmp1>
    <div style='border: solid 2px yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #adadad;'>

    </div>
</ng-template>
<div style='border: solid 2px red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #adadad;'>

</div>
```

but still i am not able to insert the element inside template

Comment: use @ViewChild for `private template: TemplateRef<any>` instead of constructor injection

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify templateURL and styleURL, it looks like you are using Angular 5, not Angular 4.  In this case, you want to put your template / html inside the template file you specified in the template.  i.e. app.component.html

Comment: it is possible even in angular 2,4.

Comment: For AngularJS 4, the attribute is 'template' inside @Componet.  The code above is using templateUrl, which is a new feature in AngularJS 5

Comment: hi @Aravind, could you please see the updaetd question of mine, i am still not able to implement it

Comment: There is no such thing as "AngularJS 4" or "AngularJS 5". AngularJS is v1.x